# Synth() and dataprep() in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that I'd like to perform synth() on. Right now I'm working on the dataprep() command and I'm running into some issues. Below is a sample of what my dataset looks like:

```
unit.number      2000     2001      2002       2003      2004 

  1               400     344        252       212       344
  2               342     234        111       102       222    
  3               244     555        512       122       152
  4               515     125        324       100       155
```

My treated unit is unit.number = 3, and the treated time period is 2004. Since I'd like to use the lagged outcome variables as predictors, I've left the data in long format. However, I also obviously want to use the years as time.variable, so I'm not sure how to do that (I originally tried inputting it as a vector with all of the year columns -- see below). Is there some way that I can make the year columns into rows as well (kind of like converting the data to wide, but while also keeping the columns present), or is there some other way that I can construct time.variable? Here is what I have so far in terms of code:

```
dataprep(foo = data, predictors = c("2000 : 2004"),
     predictors.op = c("mean"), dependent = "2004", 
     unit.variable = "unit.number", time.variable = c("2000 : 2004"), 
     treatment.identifier = 3, controls.identifier = c(1:2), 
     time.predictors.prior = c("2000 : 2003"),
     time.plot = c("2000 : 2004"))
```

I'd really appreciate some assistance with this! Thanks.